# How can I get the charset VB6 is using?

Tags: function, encoding, vb6, character-encoding

I need to find out what's the charset (encoding) my VB6 application is using.  Is there any function? Something like Encoding.Default in VB.net?

I'm converting this program to Java and they both print the same ASCII codes, but with different results (Java is using charset windows-1252).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From internal point of view, strings in VB6 are Unicode, UCS-2.

From system point of view, a VB6 app is a non-unicode application that uses the [current system character set for non-unicode applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318081%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: +1 But GetACP is a much simpler API call. No arguments and it returns the default code page. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318070(v=VS.85).aspx. From VB6 something like Declare Function GetACP Lib "kernel32" As Long.

Answer (score 0):

VB6 is tricky with encodings b/c you have at least these moving parts:

**The source code file with embedded string literals**

The VB6 editor only accepts code points, which is available in your currently selected code page. This is sometimes called "ANSI". On my system e.g. this is windows-1252 (Western Europe). It accepts German umlauts like `ä` but not `Ř` which is replaced by an `R`.

The vb file is stored windows-1252 encoded on my system. I don't know if it's b/c of a user setting or b/c of a system setting. Sorry.

**The compiler producing DLLs and other binary artifacts**

Assuming the same machine and user as the editor then builds a DLL, the string literal is then converted to a BSTR which is UTF-16 LE, i.e. with two bytes and 1 represented by `01 00`. This binary representation is put into the DLL file.

**The VB runtime string operations**

VB internally operates with BSTRs. I.e. with two bytes per code point (16bit), a string length field and probably a terminating binary zero. Concatenation, splits, trims, mids etc. work as expected within this 16bit range.

**The VB runtime when using Asc, AscW, Chr, ChrW**

The `W` variants operate on 16bit, so far so good. The non-`W` use 8bit on non-DBCS systems (and 16bit on DBCS systems, i.e. as far as I remember, on some Chinese simplified/traditional Win2000 boxes). So Asc and Chr/Chr$ need to convert between BSTR (16bit) and ANSI (8bit) codes for any code point. This is done using the executing OSs system code page (ACP).

On my box this is also 1252. Asc treats `Ř` as a `R` and returns `Asc("R")`. It can be that some code points are treated as `?` which is 63.

**The OS executing the DLL based code which might be running a different language**

Assume you actually compiled a `Ř` (which has a 16bit representation) into a DLL, e.g. via compiling a string literal of a VB file in 1250 encoding on a CP1250 box or by using `ChrW(&H158)`. If you run that on a CP1252 box where there is no 8bit representation, all is well until you need a byte value, then you get an `R` instead. This happens, when using `Asc()` or the Win32 API. See the next section.

It *might* also be affected by the version of the OS you are running the code on.

**The Win32 API which is also involved when interacting with Window elements like text boxes**

All VB6-internal Win32 API calls (with very little exceptions) and all user declared API calls are using the `...A` variant of the C API functions. They accept and yield only 8bit C strings. Any input BSTR is converted from 16bit to 8bit before and any returned 8bit C string is converted from 8bit to 16bit after the C API call.

This conversion affects API calls that manipulate a C string in a larger buffer. Inline manipulation so to speak. As far as I remember that's recognized by the types provided in the declare statement.

Note that `MyTextBox.Text = "Some Umlauts: äöü"` for a plain window text box involves a Win32 API call (a window message) and hence a 16bit to 8bit projection of the string via the system code page. Some custom-made UI elements may do this via COM and BSTR, so this projection *might* not be necessary in such a component.

**Library code besides the C API and "declare"**

I.e. COM OCX components and COM DLLs e.g.

VB uses library code via COM which normally operates on BSTR, i.e. 16bit strings, which is good in terms of localizability. However, any library is coded in a programming language and normally uses some sort of library code for string manipulation. So you can find any kind of localization "surprises" here.

This applies to loading text files from disk having any byte encoding and especially XML files which moreover have the option to specify the (probably differing) byte encoding in the payload.

Also loading from and storing strings in an SQL data-source go through COM and/or API calls.