# Bengali Unicode string is displays as "???" on Windows 7

Tags: unicode, vb6, internationalization

In my project (VB6.0), there is a label control which is displaying UNICODE string from database. everything is working fine in my machine (windows 8). when i install this to another machine (Windows 7), everything is working but UNICODE is not displaying. what should i do??? plz help.

Comment: What characters are in the string? How is the string being displayed? What font is used? Does anything show for the 'not displayed' characters? (And dear goodness.. VB6?!?)

Comment: it is bengali unicode string. there is displaying ?????? instead of bengali string.

Comment: Probably related to the font used. A "?" or "[]" (box) are often displayed the font cannot render the given glyph.

Comment: Check the setting for the "language for non-unicode programs" on the other machine. It might need to be Bengali as well.

Comment: Related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633924/vb6-text-appears-as-gibberish-in-one-exe-but-hebrew-in-another and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540361/whats-the-best-option-to-display-unicode-text-hebrew-etc-in-vb6